# Any Object except Promise?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to specify that a function accepts any Object *except* a Promise for an argument?

(I'd like the compiler to catch a missing "await" keyword.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sort of. There is a trick to disallow object types with certain properties by declaring these properties with optional [void](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void) type:

```
type NotAPromise<T> = T & { then?: void };

function f<T>(o: NotAPromise<T>) {
}

f(1); // ok
f({}); // ok 


f(Promise.resolve(2)); 

Argument of type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NotAPromise<Promise<number>>'.
  Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type '{ then?: void | undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
      Type '<TResult1 = number, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: number) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work in the playground here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAggBQE5wLYEsDO0C8UA3lMABYQB2A-AFxQBucWAJlAL4DcAUNwGYBXSgGNgWOJSh8AFHHrwkaTLggBKYt3a8ZARlU8ZRdvv7SiAQ1o7jB6Uux4AdKgg44AGwYRpAJlUmgA

Comment: @Nimai TypeScript became more strict since the answer was written. I updates the answer and it seems to work, but I'm not sure how useful it is in general anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this looking for a similar solution. Since the accepted answer doesn't constrain the parameter to the object type, here's a version that worked for me. It will accept any object except a Promise.

```
type ObjectNotPromise<T extends object> = T extends Promise<unknown>
  ? never
  : T;

function myFn<TArg extends object>(myArg: ObjectNotPromise<TArg>) {
}

myFn({}); // valid
myFn(2); // not valid
myFn(Promise.resolve("asdf")); // not valid
```

If you also don't want to allow arrays of promises (a common occurrence if you're trying to catching missing `await`s):

```
type ObjectNotPromise<T extends object> = T extends Promise<unknown>
  ? never
  : T extends Promise<unknown>[]
  ? never
  : T;

// not valid. though would be valid with the previous version of the type
myFn([Promise.resolve("foo")]);
```

The only caveat here is that empty arrays are not valid. I'm not sure how to get around that. One solution is to just cast the array to a type. E.g.

```
myFn([]); // not valid
myFn([] as unknown[]); // valid
```